# Angular Material icon fonts show as text

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm following the [Instructions here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon) to incorporate the material design icons in my [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/) app. The problem is, all the icons show up as text. e.g. if I say

```
<md-icon aria-label="Menu" class="material-icons">menu</md-icon>
```

The above will show "menu" text in the button. Am I using it all wrong? How can I use the maetrial design icons in my project?

Comment: Is you project able to ref material design js/css correctly? is there any libs missing error? If possible can you create demo fiddle for this where it can be reproduced?

Comment: Yeah it is able to ref everything correctly. It works everywhere but not when I run it in Node-Webkit